# Comparing 2 worksheets with a macro in excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to compare stock from 2 different worksheets (the master worksheet is 'Stock09042016') and generate the new result on a new sheet.  The macro should be comparing the quantity (F2) from the master worksheet to the second worksheet.  If the results are different it should copy those over to the new sheet along with all the other columns. If the results/stock are the same it shouldn't add to the new worksheet (this is where I'm lost).

Also the code below only does one row, it doesn't copy over the whole list.

**Worksheet example:**

[image: worksheet example]

**Result of macro:**

[image: Result of macro]

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim lRow, lrow2 As Long
Dim fValue As Range

Sheets("STOCK09042016").Select
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lrow2 = Sheets("STOCK26082016").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    With Sheets("STOCK26082016").Range("C2:C" & lrow2)
      Set fValue = .Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
      If fValue Is Nothing Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      End If
    End With
 Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job. I presumed you want to replace the row if the quantity is different.

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rTarget As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STOCK26082016")
    Set rSource = .Range("F2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each rCell In rSource
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

    'Try to find item
    Set rTarget = .Range("B2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Find(rCell.Offset(0, -4))

    'Check if entry for this item exist, if not copy entire row to the next empty row
    If rTarget Is Nothing Then
        rCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(1, 0)

    'If it exist, check if the quantity matches. If not, replace the row
    ElseIf Not rTarget.Offset(0, 4).Value = rCell.Value Then
        rCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=rTarget.EntireRow
    End If
    End With
 Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah that did the job.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Hursh If it solved your problem, please give it an upvote ;)